# Is there a safe way to move a partition beneath a linux software RAID5 using mdadm?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

Suppose, for example, that you have a RAID5 across multiple disks and you would like to retire the oldest of the disks and replace it with something from this decade.  I know I can fail the partition on the oldest disk and add a suitable partition from the newest disk and then wait an hour or so for the resync/recovery to complete.  However, during this process, the data is at risk.  If one of the other drives failed, I'd be boned.

I'm thinking there should be a way to tell linux software raid to mirror a pair of elements of a RAID 5 and when the mirror is complete, break off the old one.  Maybe this will illustrate.  I'm using ^ for a RAID5 and = for a mirror

1. sdb1^sdc1^sdd1
2. add sde1
3. (sde1=sdb1)^sdc1^sdd1
4. wait for sync
5. fail sdb1
6. sde1^sdc1^sdd1

Right now the only way I know to do this is

1. sdb1^sdc1^sdd1
2. fail sdb1
3. GONE^sdc1^sdd1
4. add sde1
5. wait for sync
6. sde1^sdc1^sdd1